# Generate AES key based on password only

Tags: java, security, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I have an application which may require a password for authentification.
This application does not handle any sensitive data, because this "password" is chosen by the host and told the "clients" via another channel (WhatsApp or whatever).
So when a client wants to authenticate, the host generates a random String which is sent to the client.
The client then encrypts this Random String with the password the user enters.
The encrypted random String is the sent back t the host.
The host decrypts this encrypted String with the key generated by the same password.
If the unencrypted and original String match, the user is logged in.
This is what I came up with so far:

```
String base64;
char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
String randomString = new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32);
try {
    //Encrypt Client Side
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512").generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(password)).getEncoded(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(randomString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
}
try {
    //Decrypt Server Side
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512").generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(password)).getEncoded(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    //Check if both strings match
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64)), randomString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
}
```

Unfortunately this code throws an exception: `java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Salt not found`
Should I use a different algorithm, or should I generate a salt by hashing the password itself, or a completely different approach?
I'd like to avoid having to send a generated salt along with the random String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give `PBEKeySpec` what it needs to generate enough bits for an AES key. You need the same salt on both sides, so you could do:

```
 byte[] salt = new byte[8];
 System.arraycopy(randomString.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, salt, 0, 8);
```

Now replace your `PBEKeySpec` with `new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 10, 128)` and everything should work.